# Using Flume for iSeries Server logs

Tags: ibm-midrange, flume

I am new to Flume. My organization uses iSeries (AS400) as its core platform, and, currently on V7R1M0 version.

I intend to capture our server logs for further analysis regarding performance related stuff, but could not find any documentation/nots regarding how to use Flume with iSeries.

**Can we use APACHE FLUME for logging iSeries servers, or, its exclusively for WebServers ?**

Comment: Perhaps this question might be more suited to [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/), since it doesn't seem to be a programmig question.

Comment: When you ask over on ServerFault, be sure to explain which IBM i servers you are trying to analyse.

Comment: HI guys, Thanks for suggestion. I have added it to Server Fault.

Comment: It was posted [at this link http://serverfault.com/questions/644012/apace-flume-on-ibm-iseries-and-websphere-application-servers](http://serverfault.com/questions/644012/apace-flume-on-ibm-iseries-and-websphere-application-servers)